# XML rowspan needs to update Dummy <testentry/> element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

In the xml file we have `rowspan` and their value and we need to update where the rowspan found and their cell needs to update one `<testentry/>` element.

I have a sample xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article article-type="COMPLETEDARTICLE" dtd-version="2.3" xml:lang="EN" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<table-wrap id="T1" position="float">
<label>TABLE 1</label>
<caption>
<p>Main Title.</p>
</caption>
<table>
<thead valign="top">
<tr>
<th align="center">HEAD1</th>
<th align="center">HEAD2</th>
<th align="center">HEAD3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody valign="top">
<tr>
<td rowspan="3" align="center">Prototype Fluidic Oscillator</td>
<td align="center">Throat width</td>
<td align="center">25 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">semi-spread angleOutlet</td>
<td align="center">218.6 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Feedback channel length</td>
<td align="center">50&#xb0;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="6" align="center">Throat Modified Fluidic Oscillator</td>
<td align="center">width</td>
<td align="center">25 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">semi-spread angle</td>
<td align="center">Outlet 50&#xb0;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" align="center">feedback channel Maximum length</td> #Edited Here
<td align="center">11.8 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Minimum lengthfeedback channel</td>
<td align="center">9.8 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Length of WORKFLOW</td>
<td align="center">2198 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Mixing chamber HEIGHT</td>
<td align="center">76.9 mm</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</table-wrap>
</article>
```

Tried code:

```
  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <xsl:element name="tr">
      <xsl:attribute name="style" />
      <xsl:variable name="rowspan">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::tr/child::td/@rowspan">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::tr/child::td/@rowspan)" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::tr/child::th/@rowspan">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::tr/child::th/@rowspan)" />
    </xsl:if>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="j">
    <xsl:value-of select="$rowspan" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="td-pos" select="preceding-sibling::tr[child::td/@rowspan]/position()" />
      <xsl:variable name="th-pos" select="preceding-sibling::tr[child::th/@rowspan]/position()" />
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $td-pos[last()]">
     <xsl:message select="$td-pos" />
    <xsl:message select="'debug message'">
      <xsl:value-of select="$rowspan" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$j" />
      <xsl:variable name="k" select="$rowspan" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$k" />
    </xsl:message>
    <xsl:if test="$j &gt; 0">
      <xsl:element name="testentry" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:variable name="j">
      <xsl:value-of select="$j - 1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $th-pos[last()]">
    <xsl:element name="dummyentry" />
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="child::td/@colspan|child::th/@colspan">
    <xsl:variable name="num">
      <xsl:if test="child::th/@colspan">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(child::th/@colspan)-1" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="child::td/@colspan">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(child::td/@colspan)-1" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $num">
      <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:attribute name="style" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article article-type="COMPLETEDARTICLE" dtd-version="2.3" xml:lang="EN" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<table-wrap id="T1" position="float">
<label>TABLE 1</label>
<caption>
<p>Main Title.</p>
</caption>
<table>
<thead valign="top">
<tr>
<th align="center">HEAD1</th>
<th align="center">HEAD2</th>
<th align="center">HEAD3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody valign="top">
<tr>
<td rowspan="3" align="center">Prototype Fluidic Oscillator</td>
<td align="center">Throat width</td>
<td align="center">25 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<testentry/>
<td align="center">semi-spread angleOutlet</td>
<td align="center">218.6 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<testentry/>
<td align="center">Feedback channel length</td>
<td align="center">50&#xb0;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<testentry/>
<td rowspan="2" align="center">Throat Modified Fluidic Oscillator</td>
<td align="center">width</td>
<td align="center">25 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<testentry/>
<td align="center">semi-spread angle</td>
<td align="center">Outlet 50&#xb0;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<testentry/>
<td align="center">feedback channel Maximum length</td>
<td align="center">11.8 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Minimum lengthfeedback channel</td>
<td align="center">9.8 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Length of WORKFLOW</td>
<td align="center">2198 mm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">Mixing chamber HEIGHT</td>
<td align="center">76.9 mm</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</table-wrap>
</article>
```

The output  inserting all the rows. Its wrong.

I struggled more than an hour. Could you please someone help me on this one. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose the second rowspan in your expected output should be 6 not 2?

Comment: Normally rowspan is different from morerows. rowspan in inclusive the current row. So if that is the case rowspan=3 should only give the 2 following rows een extra `testentry`. 
And when it is 6 the following 5 rows should have that `testentry` not 2, as in your example

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Apologies Question edited. Its rowspan 2. Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple xslt could give you a good start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Since rowspan could appear on both tbody and thead lets start by matching on if they have a tr with td/th with @rowspan -->
  <xsl:template match="table/*[tr/*[@rowspan]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Lets just start at the first row -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- 
    Assumption: @rowspan on entry means the amount of rows spanned inclusive the current row 
    If you think otherwise just change factorForAssumption to 0
  -->
  <xsl:variable name="factorForAssumption" select="1"/>
  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <xsl:param name="rowspanned" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rowspan" select="*[1]/@rowspan"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="$rowspanned &gt; 0">
        <testentry/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=" following-sibling::tr[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="rowspanned">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$rowspan &gt; $factorForAssumption">
            <xsl:value-of select="$rowspan - $factorForAssumption"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$rowspanned &gt; $factorForAssumption">
            <xsl:value-of select="$rowspanned - 1"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
    
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi I have one doubt. If the line `<td align="center">Outlet 50&#xb0;</td>` having another `rowspan` e.g.  `<td align="center" rowspan="2">Outlet 50&#xb0;</td>` its not working. Could you please advice.

Comment: Maybe change the source xml in your question?
Is it a logical requirement? Meaning: if i.e. the current and first previous row both have rowspan > 1 on the same td, it is not correct

Comment: Question edited. Please check and kindly do the needful.

Comment: That is new use case. Your expected outcome is not correct. I suggest you first try it changing my xslt. If you have issues, just ask a new question. We are here to help you, not to write your code.

Comment: Your source xml should also be changed. The `tr` after `<td rowspan="2" align="center">feedback channel Maximum length</td>` should have only one `td`, because of that `rowspan="2"`